# what to do (if anything) when someone posts an "answer" that's a question/request

Tags: discussion, questions

I've seen this a few times, someone must think SO is like usenet with threads, and they post a related question as an answer to someone else's question, rather than posting their own question.

[Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520902/965976#965976)

If I see this kind of post, should I flag it? or just let it be? (there aren't too many of these so they add hardly any noise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post a comment, then flag it. The user will get notified and the post will be taken away.

Downvote it if you're really feeling ornery.

Comment: I'd say it absolutely deserves a downvote. If the answer (Yes, it does say "Your Answer" when posting) doesn't address the question, it is a bad answer. Not good, not neutral.